# C# CodeDom "as" and "is" keywords functionality

Tags: c#, type-conversion, code-generation, codedom

Using CodeDom I'm looking for a way to generate c# code like this:

```
SomeRefType typedVar = obj as SomeRefType;
```

or this:

```
Boolean result = obj is SomeRefType;
```

But as far, all what I've found is [CodeCastExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codecastexpression) class which can generate explicit type casting. But this is not what I need.
Is there any way to implement "as" and "is" keywords functionality using CodeDom?

Comment: Oh. It seems "operator" word did the trick. I'll check it...

Answer (score 1):

For history. Apparently, there's no universal way to implement these operators with CodeDom model.

It is possible to use CodeSnippetExpression to generate necessary code. But the solution becomes dependent on the target language used.

```
statements.Add(new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("SomeRefType", "typedVar", new CodeSnippetExpression("obj as SomeRefType")));
statements.Add(new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("Boolean", "result", new CodeSnippetExpression("obj is SomeRefType")));
```

Another option is to replace these operators with effectively similar logic. So for `is` operator the code is something like that:

```
statements.Add(new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("Boolean", "result", new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeTypeOfExpression("SomeRefType"), "IsInstanceOfType", new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("obj"))));
// Boolean result = typeof(SomeRefType).IsInstanceOfType(obj);
```

and for `as` opeartor like that:

```
statements.Add(new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("SomeRefType", "typedVal"));
statements.Add(new CodeConditionStatement(
    new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeTypeOfExpression("SomeRefType"), "IsInstanceOfType", new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("obj")),
    new CodeStatement[] { 
        new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("typedVal"), new CodeCastExpression("SomeRefType", new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("obj")))
    },
    new CodeStatement[] {
        new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("typedVal"), new CodePrimitiveExpression(null))
    }));
// SomeRefType typedVal = typeof(SomeRefType).IsInstanceOfType(obj) ? (SomeRefType)obj : null;
```

The generated IL-code is different from the code which is generated when using `is` and `as` operators. But in this case the target language can be any.